# Is there a word to describe the intentional act of seeking someone’s envy?

Tags: single-word-requests

Trying to find a word that can best describe the above situation. So many words seem to describe feelings of envy, but nothing seems to fit the case of someone who thrives on encouraging it.

Comment: Look up synonyms for 'to brag' if that is not strong enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is the word ***flaunt***

Defined by [Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flaunt) as:

> Display (something) ostentatiously, especially in order to provoke envy or admiration or to show defiance.
>   *‘newly rich consumers eager to flaunt their prosperity’*

Answer (score 0):

The word *flaunt* could possibly be what you're looking for. Someone could flaunt XYZ to stir up reactions of envy in others.

Envy, as defined by the Oxford dictionary is, "a feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else's possessions, qualities, or luck."

Which is caused by someone making an either subtle, unintentional, or obvious/intentional display of the coveted thing. And that's usually by flaunting, a better word than bragging.

"Flaunting: [to] display (something) ostentatiously, especially in order to **provoke envy or admiration** or to show defiance." - Oxford Dictionary

Comment: Beat ya by 4 mins :-(  Also if you are including a dictionary definition, please remember to cite your source (and include a link if the source is online).

Comment: Ack, sorry! The page refreshed when I posted. I'll add the citations... or should I just delete it if it's a repeat?